# Otimização de ferramenta de busca personalizada

Tags: php, wordpress, if, algoritmo-de-busca, switch

Galera, estou criando uma página de busca que recebe, via `POST`, as informações de um formulário contendo vários `checkbox`. Vejam abaixo que há várias sequências de resultados e está marcado em laranja uma delas como exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clicar em **procurar**, as informações são enviadas para uma página onde conterá uma sequencia de `if` e `case` para organizar as informações:

```
    if(!isset($_POST['residencial']) && 
        isset($_POST['comercial']) && 
        isset($_POST['mecanico']) &&
        !isset($_POST['eletronico']) &&
        isset($_POST['chave']) &&
        isset($_POST['segredo']) &&
        !isset($_POST['display']) &&
        !isset($_POST['led'])){

        $var1 = $_POST['residencial'].'+'.
        $_POST['mecanico'].'+'.
        $_POST['display'];

    }

echo $var1;
```

**RESULTADO:** comercial + mecanico + chave + segredo

Depois que trato essas informações, eu as trato em um `switch`:

```
switch ($var1){

        case 'comercial + mecanico + chave + segredo ':
            $data = array(
            '1'  => $_POST['chave'],
            '2'  => $_POST['segredo']
        );
break;
```

Por fim, utilizo o `$data` para filtrar meu loop:

```
   $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                // 'terms' => 'white-wines'
                'terms' => array(
                    $data['1'], 
                    $data['2']
                    )
                )
        ),
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title,'
    );
```

---

### **MINHA DÚVIDA:**

Como posso otimizar isto? Tudo funciona bem, mas como os checkbox tem muitas possibilidades, o código está ficando **imenso!**

**Combinações:**
(comercial+residencial+mecanico+eletronico+chave+segredo+display+led)

(comercial e/ou residencial + mecanico e/ou eletronico + chave e/ou segredo e/ou display e/ou led)

---

### **UPDATE:**

> O problema é que há uma combinação de check! Exemplo: existe o chave para comercial e chave para residencial e alem disso a chave pode ou não ser mecânico ou elétrico! Como faço nesse caso?

Há uma hierarquia entre os check:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Comercial(categoria)
-Mecânico(sub categoria)
--Chave(sub)
--Segredo(sub)
--Display(sub)
--Led (sub)

-Eletrônico(sub categoria)
--Chave(sub)
--Segredo(sub)
--Display(sub)
--Led (sub)

Residencial(categoria)
-Mecânico
--Chave
--Segredo
--Display
--Led 

-Eletrônico
--Chave
--Segredo
--Display
--Led
```

Comment: Porque que quando isso aqui ocorre:
`case 'comercial + mecanico + chave + segredo ':
            $data = array(
            '1'  => $_POST['chave'],
            '2'  => $_POST['segredo']
        );
break;`

você só joga dois posts na array?

Comment: É um exemplo para o caso da imagem acima, pois perceba que `chave` e `segredo` estão selecionados!

Comment: Olha, pode não ter considerado o que o Dudu disse, mas daqueles ifs ele já te salvou, o que sugiro é usar array_push () para aqueles dados dentro do switch.

E tua pergunta tá meio confusa, se a gente te responder, provavelmente vai ter mais uma excessão no seu código que não está claro.

Comment: O problema é que vocês não estão entendendo que estou utilizando o resquest post para formar um valor para `$var1`. Só quero saber como faço a soma  `comercial + mecanico + chave + segredo`, sem utilizar muitos códigos. Essa soma vai determinar lá no **switch ($var1)**. Como diferencio quem é quem quando se tem subcategoria? Veja o update que fiz! Está claro.

Comment: @Lollipop Seria algo assim: http://pastebin.com/6kB56ksg ? Acho que entendi +- o que você quer fazer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E se você fizer algo assim não te ajuda?

```
<?php
function ohGogWhy($postData) {
    //query categories
    $categories = array(
        'comercial' => array(
            'eletronico', 
            'mecanico'
        ), 

        'residencial' => array(
            'eletronico', 
            'mecanico'
        )
    );

    $slug = array(
        'comercial' => 'co',
        'eletronico' => 'ele',
        'residencial' => 're',
        'mecanico' => 'mec'
    );

    $mainArr = isset($postData['main'])? $postData['main'] : array_keys($categories);
    $subArr = isset($postData['sub']) ? $postData['sub'] : $categories;

    $dataArr = array();

    //main
    if (isset($postData['subsub'])) {

        foreach($postData['subsub'] as $subsub) {

            foreach($mainArr as $main) {

                $tsub = (isset($subArr[$main])) ? $subArr[$main] : $subArr;

                foreach($tsub as $sub)
                    $data[] = $subsub . '-' . str_replace(array_keys($slug), array_values($slug), $main . '-' . $sub);
            }
        }
    }
    elseif (isset($postData['sub'])) {
        foreach($mainArr as $main) {

                $tsub = (isset($subArr[$main])) ? $subArr[$main] : $subArr;

                foreach($tsub as $sub)
                    $data[] = $sub . '-' . str_replace(array_keys($slug), array_values($slug), $main);
            }
    }
    else {
        $data = $mainArr;
    }

    return $data;
}

$data = array();
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $data = ohGogWhy($_POST);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
}

?>
<html>
    <title>lol</title>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            main:
            <input type="checkbox" name="main[]" value="comercial" multiple="false" />Comercial
            <input type="checkbox" name="main[]" value="residencial" multiple="false" />Residencial
            <hr>
            sub:
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub[]" value="mecanico" />Mecanico
            <input type="checkbox" name="sub[]" value="eletrico" />Eletronico
            <hr/>
            subsub:
            <input type="checkbox" name="subsub[]" value="chave" />Chave
            <input type="checkbox" name="subsub[]" value="segredo" />Segredo
            <input type="checkbox" name="subsub[]" value="display" />Display
            <input type="checkbox" name="subsub[]" value="led" />Led
            <hr>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

As validações pra selecionar apenas um elemento tu faz por JS

Answer (score 0):

Para facilitar você pode montar um vetor de checkboxes no HTML onde **o valor do campo é o termo a se buscar**, assim seu formulário ficaria dessa forma:

```
<input name="termos[]" type="checkbox" value="comercial">
<input name="termos[]" type="checkbox" value="residencial">
<input name="termos[]" type="checkbox" value="mecanico">
<input name="termos[]" type="checkbox" value="eletronico">
<input name="termos[]" type="checkbox" value="chave">
<input name="termos[]" type="checkbox" value="segredo">
<input name="termos[]" type="checkbox" value="display">
<input name="termos[]" type="checkbox" value="led">
```

Quando esse formulário é recebido no PHP você terá um vetor de termos `$_POST['termos']` que pode ser inserido diretamente na sua busca e assim dispensa o tratamento que você está fazendo na primeira parte do código:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_POST['termos']
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'title,'
);
```

Comment: Aí funciona igual, é só você trocar o checkbox por radios.